# Proper Routing in Mongolab

Tags: javascript, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mlab

I am trying to create a web application with Heroku and the mongoLab add-on.  I have followed the instructions on the Heroku website and can connect to my mongoLab db with the following code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uriUtil = require('mongodb-uri');

var options = { server: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 } },
    replset: { socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1, connectTimeoutMS : 30000 } } };

var mongodbUri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
var mongooseUri = uriUtil.formatMongoose(mongodbUri);

mongoose.connect(mongooseUri, options);

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("connection successful");
});
```

Typically, when doing my routing I will do something like the following.

```
var Test;
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    test: String,
});

Test = mongoose.model('Test', testSchema);

module.exports = {Test: Test};
```

Then I can easily reference my Test model in my routes files by doing a simple var Models = require("./models") and a Models.Test.find(callback) within a http request.

**Question:** What is best practice for adding this same functionality with a mongolab database?  I can create schemas and manually write code to add records to my database within db.once, but I want to be able to do all the basic CRUD commands via http requests in a separate javaScript file.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, it looks like defining the routes and starting the express server within db.once is best practice.  Here is a link to what I found.

[Routing with MongoLab](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/KZjYMrIRAzw)